# Retrieving Month and Year from a date in SAS

Tags: date, sas

I am comparing dates from two tables.
Values1 = 28/07/2020
Values2 = 26/06/2020
I tried using the intnx function. it doesnt provide the right results.
it should compare only the month and year and spit out the differences

Comment: Please share the exact code you tried and a data step that produces the inputs. Please post these as text, not as an image, and please update your question rather than posting extra details in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

`intnx` is for advancing or retreating a date value to another date value.

The correct function for computing intervals is `INTCK`.

```
* variables contain SAS date values;

month_diff = intck ('month', values1, values2);
```